# Search for rows in a 2D array that contain a given sequence

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, asynchronous, search

I have a 2d array of **m * n** dimension (m and n can vary from 1 to 100000). The following snippet of code checks if the sequence exists in the row and stores the index if it exists. **The time taken by the following code on 10000*10000 matrix is 650 milliseconds. The sequential version of the code also takes the same time.**

**This on Intel Core i7-7560U CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <future>

std::vector<int> lps;

void ComputeLPSArray(std::vector<int> const &pattern) {

    std::vector<int> lps(pattern.size());
    int len = 0;

    lps[0] = 0;

    int i = 1;
    while (i < (int) pattern.size()) {
        if (pattern[i] == pattern[len]) {
            len++;
            lps[i] = len;
            i++;
        } else {
            if (len != 0) {
                len = lps[len - 1];
            } else {
                lps[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}


int SearchPattern(std::vector<int> const &pattern, std::vector<int> const &row) {
    auto M = (int) pattern.size();
    auto N = (int) row.size();

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < N) {

        if (pattern[j] == row[i]) {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        if (j == M) {
            return 1;
        } else if (i < N && pattern[j] != row[i]) {
            if (j != 0)
                j = lps[j - 1];
            else
                i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

std::vector<int> SearchSequence(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const &matrix, std::vector<int> const &sequence) {

    ComputeLPSArray(sequence);
    std::vector<int> result(matrix.size());
    unsigned int length = 0;
    std::vector<std::future<int>> f(matrix.size());

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        std::vector<int> row = matrix[i];
        f[i] = async(std::launch::async, [sequence, row] { return SearchPattern(sequence, row); });
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < f.size(); ++i) {
        if (f[i].get() == 1)
            result[length++] = i;
    }

    result.resize(length);

    return result;
}

int main() {

    int m = 25, n = 20; // assume `m` and `n` can vary.
    std::vector<std::vector<int >> matrix(m, std::vector<int>(n));

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 1000;
        }

    }

    std::vector<int> sequence = matrix[24]; // This is purely for testing purpose, actual input(matrix&sequence) is read from files.

    std::vector<int> result;
    result = SearchSequence(matrix, sequence); // This is the ONLY function which needs to be optimised.

    return 0;
}
```

**How do I speed up the search time in this scenario?**

Comment: what does the matrix store? any int up to about 2^32?

Comment: @juvian, Yes, The matrix contains integers.

Comment: Do you know any context of where is this used? Is it likely for the sequence to be present in many rows? You could keep a structure like hashmap or set to know which ints are in each row and avoid doing KMPSearchPattern on rows that do not have one of the ints in the sequence

Comment: @juvian, Yes, It is likely that sequence to be present in many rows. I have tried the **hashmap** version also instead of KMP but that didn't help much. I am looking for optimisation in data designing point of view than algorithmic point of view.

Comment: It should greatly reduce time if few rows have all ints in the sequence. Is the amount of things in sequence always the same?

Comment: @juvian You are just considering the algorithm's complexity without considering memory cache. I have benchmarked with KMP and hashmap version, The time didn't change much. And No, The size of sequence can vary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83795/discussion-between-adithya-potlapelli-and-juvian).

Comment: What is `lps`? Looks like some means to avoid restarting the matching from the start of the pattern. You should edit the question to make it complete - compilable, include the tests (maybe use some pseudo-random generator) and maybe add your PC specs (number of cores, hyper-threading, speed).

Comment: @firda I have updated with code to compute `lps` and PC config.

Comment: @AdithyaPotlapelli: That is better, but I am still not quite sure it belongs here as it is. You seem to be asking very specific thing - how to speed that up, but we here usually look at the code as a whole - so I could immediately complain about `lhs` being global while you pass `pattern` as parameter - bad design. It would certainly help to have full code (as suggested, including generator), but you could still receive reviews more about the code itself than about how to speed it up. Maybe such a question would fit better on some ohter SE site, really not sure here.

Comment: @firda, I have updated the question with compilable code.

Comment: Is it necessary to make a copy of each row of the matrix to pass to the threads?  Or could you pass a pointer to it instead?  You're potentially creating an excessive number of threads.

Comment: I don't suppose you could post a new version of the code that doesn't (A) require 10,000 user threads, nor (B) segfault even with `m=10` and `n=10`? It's hard to compare apples and apples when the code posted doesn't run (and in fact crashes) on most normal computers. But certainly it'll run faster if you pass/capture more things by reference instead of by value. You're copying the world at least twice.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm When I pass the matrix by reference, for next thread calls it becomes the variable that has already been destructed due to stack unwinding which'll result in `segfault`.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I changed `m` and `n` to `25` and `20` and I didn't get any `segfault`. If I pass by reference to the lambda, for next thread calls it becomes the variable that has already been destructed due to stack unwinding which'll result in `segfault`.

Comment: `auto& row = matrix[i];` and `async(std::launch::async, [&sequence, &row]` I suppose.

Comment: @firda That worked but there isn't any significant difference in the performance.

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote your `SearchSequence` function to be as absolutely brain-dead as possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

std::vector<int> SearchSequence(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const &matrix, std::vector<int> const &sequence)
{
    std::vector<int> result;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++) {
        auto it = std::search(matrix[i].begin(), matrix[i].end(), sequence.begin(), sequence.end());
        if (it != matrix[i].end()) {
            result.emplace_back(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {

    int m = 25000, n = 25000; // assume `m` and `n` can vary.
    std::vector<std::vector<int >> matrix(m, std::vector<int>(n));

    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 1000;
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> sequence = matrix[9999]; // This is purely for testing purpose, actual input(matrix&sequence) is read from files.

    auto initial_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout
        << "Initializing the array with rand() took: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(initial_time - start_time).count() << " ms\n";

    std::vector<int> result = SearchSequence(matrix, sequence); // This is the ONLY function which needs to be optimised.

    auto search_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout
        << "Executing the actual search took: "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(search_time - initial_time).count() << " ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

On my laptop, this prints:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 ./x.cc
$ ./a.out
Initializing the array with rand() took: 5304 ms
Executing the actual search took: 2 ms

$ clang++ -std=c++14 -O0 ./x.cc
$ ./a.out
Initializing the array with rand() took: 7670 ms
Executing the actual search took: 8 ms
```

This is single-threaded, with absolutely no cleverness to the search at all — I'm just using the $O(n^2)$ [`std::search` algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) from the standard library.

I suggest that your business with `std::vector<std::future<int>>` is completely unnecessary, and that if you're measuring any slowness, it's slowness in *initializing the matrix with random numbers*.

Comment: The complexity of `std::search` is linear in *count1*count2*  (where countX is the distance between firstX and lastX). so, theoretically what I implemented must be better than `std::search`. And the real question is how can I reduce the actual search time? Why *threads* aren't really helping in this scenario? Also, the time for initialising array isn't a concern here because I am reading the large array from file.

Comment: Yes, but when you say your code is slow, you mean your code for *initializing the array* is slow! The actual search, on a 25000 x 25000 array, is so fast as to be almost impossible to measure. Adding the overhead of reading from disk, or thread spawning and synchronization, or anything else, is just going to slow you down, in this case.

Comment: "theoretically what I implemented must be better than `std::search`": Yes! Modulo bugs, *theoretically* what you implemented *is* better than `std::search`. But *in practice* what you implemented is much *worse* than `std::search`. You forgot to account for the [constant factor](https://wcipeg.com/wiki/Hidden_constant_factor): spawning a single thread is a complex operation that might involve the equivalent of *several* 25000-element-array-traversals just in order to create the new thread and all its bookkeeping.

Comment: @AdithyaPotlapelli Isn't KMP meant to improve the worst case of searching (many repeated elements in the pattern and sequence)? I'm not sure what your actual data looks like, but I suspect random integers are unlikely to show any benefit from using KMP over the normal `std::search` algorithm.

Comment: @user673679 I've taken that into consideration. I have repeated elements in the pattern and sequence. So I thought KMP might have an edge over `std::search`.

Comment: How many positions in the haystack will we search, on average, using the "dumb" O(n^2) algorithm? Well, we'll look at the first int. With probability 999/1000, our search ends there — we learn that the needle cannot be at this position, and there are no other possible positions for a length-25000 needle in this length-25000 haystack, so we're done. So the "dumb" algorithm reads an expected 25025 ints' worth of data, and doesn't write or copy any data. It's going to be hard to beat that! Try some different inputs; but *start* with the dumb algorithm as your baseline. Premature optimization...

Comment: @Quuxplusone Can you please update your answer with your PC configuration?

Comment: @AdithyaPotlapelli: Well, it's a MacBook from circa 2012. Doesn't really matter; your numbers will be similar (at least insofar as the ratio between them).